# Bootstrap Studio: Adding border to elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, bootstrap-studio

As far as I know there is no way to add a border to an element via the `bootstrap-studio` user interface. The only way you can do it is either through `css` or adding the `boostrap` border class: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/

So I am adding e.g. `border-dark` to Class Names, which doesn't work for me:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add next to `border-dark` for the color also the direction e.g. `border-left` `border-right` `border-top` `border-bottom`